# What is this square, italic brush font?

Tags: font-identification

I have found this website screenshot on [Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/141300507034417190/). I have just tried Myfont.com's font identifier ("What the font?"), but it has returned nothing distantly similar.

Is there a font similar to this available somewhere? I think it's a brush font.

[image]

Comment: Ask [him](https://www.behance.net/Rique). He is the author for the images.

Comment: I tried searching it for you via [What The Font](http://whatthefont.com/) but did not found it.
Do you have a PDF version of it, the font info is mostly stored in the properties of the file.

Answer (score 1):

There are some similar fonts:

- [Giants](http://www.1001fonts.com/giants-font.html)
- [VTKS](http://www.1001fonts.com/vtks-highlight-font.html)
- [Markus](http://www.1001fonts.com/markus-ink-font.html)
- [Airship](http://www.losttype.com/font/?name=airship) - similar shape but without the marker effect

Comment: When suggesting fonts pkease include a screenshot of the font